# Missing @ Symbol when using $this->input->get()

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am currently practicing making a joomla MVC component and so far everything works well except that when I submit a form with an element like this

```
<input type="text" value="" name="email" placeholder="your-email@domain.com" />
```

with a value like below for example

```
email@domain.com
```

All I am getting in the `JControllerLegacy` is `emaildomain.com`. Notice the missing `@`.

I am getting the form value by

```
$email= $this->input->get('email');
```

Is this a feature of Joomla that I am not aware of?

Comment: well I really don't know, but if it is a feature, then it is a bad one for sure :)

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: Agreed.  But it might have a bit to do with the intended audience.  I wouldn't be surprised if most punctuation (and particularly `$`, `'`, `"`, and `;`)  got filtered out as well, to protect people from their own noobness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, the said issue is because of Joomla filter [options](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput#Getting_Values).

You can try something like this,

```
$email= $this->input->get('email',null,'string'); //or HTML for allow html tags
```

For older Joomla versions check [this](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest::getVar)

Hope it will work.

Comment: This works! :) Thank you very much! This is very troublesome to guys like us still learning Joomla.

Comment: @Kuma Glad to know its helps, then accept as answer so in future some guys found it useful!